# Passing functional props with typescript in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function, react-props

I am going to pass a functional props from parent to a child component with typescript:

```
import react, {Component} from 'react'
import Child from './Child'
//some type declaration
class Parent extends Component<{IProps},{IState}> {
state = {
id: 0;
name:'sample'
}
//some code
//I do not know how to declare type of below function!!!
onChildClickedHandler = (target:HTMLInputElement)=> {
this.setState({id:target.id})
}
render () {
<div>
<Child onChildClicked = {this.onChildClickedHandler} name={this.state.name} />
</div>
}
}

export default Parent
```

---

```
import React from 'react'
interface IChild  {
//I do not know how to declare type of below function!!!
onChildClicked: ({target:HTMLInputElement}) => void
name:string
}
const Child : React.SFC<IChild> = ({onChildClicked, name}) => {
return (<div>
<button type="text" id="1" onClick={({target})=>onChildClicked(target)}>
{name}
</button>
<button type="text" id="2" onClick={({target})=>onChildClicked(target)}>
    {name}
    </button>
</div>)

}
```

---

I used destructuring for getting `target` instead of `event.target` to pass to the function.
 How can I declare type for `onChildClicked` function in Child stateless component in a correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems:
When you click an Element a `MouseEvent` happens which can be defined by `React.MouseEvent`. now you can specify that `MouseEvent` happened on what element by `React.MouseEvent<HTML***Element>`

Now that your click happens on a button in child, the `event.target` contains props of that Element tag. for instance `<button name="bla" id="bla" onClick={***} />` the event contains `name`, `id`, and ofcourse the tagname itself.

So a general click event is like

```
handleClick(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>)

// Destructuring `target` from `even` and `name, id` from `target` will look like 

handleClick({target:{name,id}}: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>)
```

so your interface should look like

```
onChildClicked: ({target:{name,id}}: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void
```

For more Event types (specifically mouse events) check the [type declaration of React](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/v15/index.d.ts#L696) by [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react)